# How to hide folder directory? with htaccess is it possible?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website has the structure www.mywebsite.com/app/views/pages/dashboard.php however I wanted it to be only www.mywebsite.com/dashboard.php I tried to do this with htaccess but I'm not getting results

This is my complete htaccess

```html
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  satisfy all
</files>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dashboard\.php$ app/view/pages/dashboard.php
```

Comment: Are you still using Apache 2.2?

Comment: Apache/2.4.38 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2q PHP/5.6.40

Comment: Try using Apache 2.4 syntax then

Comment: Is my code logic right?

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: In the root folder within public_html